# Google map api v3, how to add polygons to custom overlay

Tags: google-maps-api-3

The following site : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays shows how to create image overlay using customoverlays but how do I use the same technique for creating polygons using customoverlays. The map that I am using comes from the following example http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latlng-to-coord-control/latlng-to-coord-control.html . However, when I added polygons to the map, it is unable to display lat/long/pixel values when I moved the mouse over the polygons. I thought that if I created the polygons using custom overlays the problems will be solved. I have created image overlays using custom overlays and it is able to display the correct lat/lng/pixel values when I moved the mouse over the image. Therefore I think if I create the polygons using custom overlays, it should work also but I could not find examples on how to do that. Please advise.

Updated Code:

```
aoiPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({ 
  paths: polyCoords, 
  strokeColor: '#FF0000', 
  strokeOpacity: 0.8, 
  strokeWeight: 2, 
  fillColor: '#FF0000', 
  fillOpacity: 0.35, 
  clickable:false 
}); 
aoiPoly.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the [polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolygonOptions) to `clickable:false`?

Comment: I re-examined my code and tried setting clickable:false for the polygons. Now it works! Thank you very much for the answer, geocodezip. Here is the code :   aoiPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
       paths: polyCoords,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
   clickable:false
    });

    aoiPoly.setMap(map);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `clickable:false` on the [google.maps.Polygons](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PolygonOptions), they will be prevented from intercepting the mouse events.

```
clickable | boolean | Indicates whether this Polygon handles mouse events. Defaults to true
```

Comment: Yes, I realize this also but I do not know of anyway that allow mouse events over the Polygons and at the same time allow the display of coordinates when mouse is over the Polygons using the LatLngControl method in the Google's sample code (http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latlng-to-coord-control/latlng-to-coord-control.htm ).