# Cant GetPosition in Overlay Polygon Zone

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

im getting the current position (latitude and Longitude) on the map when a user click on it, and works fine the script, it gives me the position of the place i clicked in the map, the problem is that doesnt work when i click in the colored polygon zones.

I already try to figure out how to solve it, but but cant figure out the solution.

I leave here the link above:
http://jsbin.com/nirikuwofo/edit?html,output

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google map api v3, how to add polygons to custom overlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469675/google-map-api-v3-how-to-add-polygons-to-custom-overlay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `clickable: false` to all the polygons. That way the click will go trough the polygon and will click the map underneath. E.g.:

```
var zone1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: zone1_Coords,
    strokeColor: '#d9dc02',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#f5f801',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
    ,clickable:false // <-- ADD THIS LINE
  });
```

http://jsbin.com/sokugoziso/1/edit?html,output