# click on map doesn't get triggered when the click is on a polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polygon

I have a simple google maps map and when I click on it I want an alert to be triggered:

```
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
  
  const triangleCoords = [
    { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    { lat: -33.5, lng: 152 },
    { lat: -34.4, lng: 149 },
  ];
  const triangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
     paths: triangleCoords,
  });
  triangle.setMap(map);
        
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", (e) => {
  alert('there was a click')
  const result = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(
     e.latLng,
     triangle
  );
  
  if(result)alert('inside triangle')
  else alert('outside triangle')
});

}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqupyw9g/14/)

However, when I click on the polygon, the event doesn't get triggered, the alert is not firing. Outside of the polygon it does work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you remove `triangle.setMap(map)`, this works, but you won't have the highlighted region. setMap is probably creating a new map of the selected area, which overrides the existing event listener. So you will have to add the event listener to this again. You may also check setMarker instead of using this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [google.maps.Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon) captures click when it is "clickable" (defaults to true).  If you set `clickable:false`, the `map` click listener function will run.  From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#PolygonOptions.clickable):

> **clickable** optional
> Type:  boolean optional
> Indicates whether this Polygon handles mouse events. Defaults to true.

Related question: [Cant GetPosition in Overlay Polygon Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161550/cant-getposition-in-overlay-polygon-zone)

(the other option would be to leave the `Polygon` as `clickable:true`, but add the same event listener to the `Polygon`)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gd4nr9ye/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8,
  });

  const triangleCoords = [{
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    {
      lat: -33.5,
      lng: 152
    },
    {
      lat: -34.4,
      lng: 149
    },
  ];
  const triangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    clickable: false
  });
  triangle.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", (e) => {
    alert('there was a click')
    const result = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(
      e.latLng,
      triangle
    );

    if (result) alert('inside triangle')
    else alert('outside triangle')
    /* console.log(result) */

  });

}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```